# Preventing user model from loading multiple times in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a situation where the user model is used multiple times in the same query in different places. For example: I want to iterate through all the groups the users is a member of, and get a unique list of all his/her friends that are also members of these groups.

Right now the user model gets reloaded every time, which results in:
1) Performance hit
2) Ideally I would use an instance variable to hold the unique list of friends, but I cannot do it since the user model gets reloaded.

It would make a lot of sense for the user model to be global for the duration of the request - any idea how I could achieve that?

Comment: Can you post your same query so we can take a look at it? In general you should be able to avoid multiple queries by taking advantage of instance variables, preloading, eager loading, or joining. Some more information will help us find what's right for you. In the mean time, try looking up these terms in Rails and you may find what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that with "the user model" you actually means the current user instance (the User model is used to reference the model defined bu the class User) you normally use a memoization technique.

For instance, given you have a `current_user` method in your controller, you can do

```
def current_user
  return @current if defined?(@current)
  # In the following line load the current user. It's the first time
  # this method is requested. Further calls will return the cached instance.
  @current = ...
end
```

Comment: not the case... I'm already doing it for the current user. Need something to prevent any user model from loading multiple times

Answer (score 0):

You can set a user like this:

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(1)
end
```